# SoftEther Server Not Saving Configuration

Tags: vpn, softether

I'm running a Softether server, but I have this peculiar problem that when I change settings using `vpncmd` those changes are NOT persisted to my `vpn_server.config` file. But to my knowledge, it should be? Is the configuration actually stored somewhere else?

Until I can solve this I have to reconfigure my server every time I reboot my machine.

Comment: Why don’t you edit the configuration file by hand?

Comment: I haven't found any documentation as to how to do that. Like, what does a complete added user item look like? How do I hash the password? etc. Again, because it's not being written out I have no idea what those look like. I did however find out about the `Flush` command in `vpncmd` that will force it to be written to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that there's a command you can execute inside `vpncmd`, `Flush` that will write the current server configuration to `vpn_server.config`. So, every time I make a change I just have to call `Flush` and I'm golden.